# get data byte[] in real time using camera2 api

Tags: android, real-time, android-camera2

I am working on Camera2 api with real time Image processing, i get
found method

```
onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureSession, CaptureRequest, CaptureResult)
```

call on every capturing fram but i have no idea how to get  **byte[]** or data from **CaptureResult**

Answer (score 0):

You can't get image data from CaptureResult; it only provides image metadata.

Take a look at the [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample app, which captures JPEG images with an ImageReader.  If you change the JPEG format to YUV, set the resolution to preview size, and set the ImageReader Surface as a target for the preview repeating request, you'll get an ImageReader.Image for every frame captured.

Comment: can you snippet please?